# Neo4j APOC A* with conditions

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have successfully used the following to get the shortest path using A* in the APOC library.

```
apoc.algo.aStar("A", "B", 'Link', 'Length','X','Y') YIELD path, weight

apoc.algo.aStar("A", "B", 'Link', {weight:'Length',default:1, x:'X',y:'Y'}) YIELD path, weight
```

How would I go about adding a filter so that it only uses edges where "Value" is true. The [documentation](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) doesn't provide an example.

```
public class Node{
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public long X {get;set;}
    public long Y {get;set;}
}

public class Link{
   public bool Value {get;set;}
   public long Length {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no example because this feature is not available.

So you have three choices :

- add a `Length` value very high on relationships where "Value" is true
- modify your model by adding the property "Value" in the relationship type (ie to have two types : `Link_On` and `Link_value_Off`), so you can use the apoc procedure.
- create your own A* procedure by taking example on the one from APOC ([source code here](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/39559c80aeb510d4dfe9adb0354354eb23a34604/src/main/java/apoc/algo/PathFinding.java))